# Programmatically add domains to Google reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: subdomain, recaptcha

I am working on adding Google reCAPTCHA v3 to FreeToastHost, a free forms & template based website generator/content management system specifically made for use by Toastmasters public speaking clubs around the world.

One challenge I have in implementing this is that in addition to our use of a root domain and subdomains for accessing each club's website, we also support each club purchasing their own "custom website domain" through a registrar which they they tie to our server's IP address via their DNS settings.

We do require that each club save these "custom domain names" in the system (gets stored in our db) so we can still generate their website by looking up their custom domain in our db to fetch their content.  At this point we have about 80 clubs of the 12000+ using the system that also have custom domains.

I will not know these custom domains in advance, so I have had to just register our root domain for Google reCAPTCHA v3, shut off the domain checking setting because of the custom domains, and resolve to do our own domain checking.

I would prefer that Google do the domain checking, but without an API to add domains programmatically / dynamically and with their 50 domain limit per key-pair, I am just not sure what else to do other than doing our own domain checking.

Anyone have any fresh ideas on this?

Comment: I would like to clarify one aspect of the aforesaid implementation. Since you have one key-pair covering your root domain and all the subdomains for 12000+ clubs, the ML model that is used for reCAPTCHA v3 is common across the different clubs' websites, right? Is that intended? Having only a single model would bias the predictions made on each individual website. I would love to hear your thoughts on that. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Also, were you able to find a better implementation for your issue?

Comment: Just saw the responses...  Yes, I do think that some bias is likely, but I am not sure how to better set up reCAPTHCA v3 on a case by case basis for each club website.